# Error creating table in phpMyAdmin (wampserver) via SQL code

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

Error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'create table android_php_post(
>       id int(5) primary key auto_increment,
>      nam'
>   at line 3

My Code

```
USE android_login

create table android_php_post(
   id int(5) primary key auto_increment,
   name varchar(40) not null,
   email varchar(50) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   gender varchar(6) not null,
   age int(6) not null
);
```

---

I really just don't understand what's wrong with the syntax of the code so I'm thinking that it must be something else? It also errors with the same thing even when I use no parameters at all. As in the code below also displays an error message to check the syntax in the manual for the code near 'create table.'

```
USE android_login

create table android_php_post(
);
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a semi-colon after `USE android_login`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Nice job including all the relevant information in your question though. Doesn't seem to happen enough

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I am so annoyed with myself that I didn't pick up on the missing semicolon, ugh.